# Splitting one file into many with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file called one_to_many.txt. In the file is the data:

```
a,aaa
b,bbb
c,ccc
```

I want to use powershell to create 3 files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt

File a.txt to contain data "aaa", b to contain "bbb ...

I'm new to Powershell and can't work out how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
Get-Content one_to_many.txt | Foreach-Object {
  $fileName, $content = $_ -split ','
  $content | Set-Content "$fileName.txt"
}
```

`Get-Content` reads the file and returns lines, one by one. Each line is piped to `Foreach-Object` where it can be accessed as `$_`.

You need to split the line by comma, so invoke operator `-split` which returns in this case array of 2 items. The assignment `$filename, $content = ..` causes that content of first item in array (from `-split`) is assigned to `$filename` and the rest to `$content.

Then simply store that content in the file via `Set-Content`